# Removing invalid child nodes but keep its contents intact..?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml files that look like [sample file](https://codeshare.io/2pz4MX)

I want to remove invalid `xref` nodes from it but keep the contents of those nodes as it is.

The way to know whether a `xref` node is valid is to check its attribute `rid`'s value exactly matches any of the attributes `id` of any node present in the entire file, so the output file of the above sample should be something like [sample output file](https://codeshare.io/2KwR4o)

The code I've written thus far is below

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(@"D:\sample\sample.xml",LoadOptions.None);


            var ids = from a in doc.Descendants()
                where a.Attribute("id") !=null
                select a.Attribute("id").Value;
            var xrefs=from x in doc.Descendants("xref")
                where x.Attribute("rid")!=null
                select x.Attribute("rid").Value;
            if (ids.Any() && xrefs.Any())
            {
                foreach(var xref in xrefs)
                {
                    if (!ids.Contains(xref))
                    {

                        string content= File.ReadAllText(@"D:\sample\sample.xml");
                        string result=Regex.Replace(content,"<xref ref-type=\"[^\"]+\" rid=\""+xref+"\">(.*?)</xref>","$1");
                        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\sample\sample.xml",result);
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No value found");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is when the values of `xref` contain characters like `., *, (`etc. which on a regex replace needs to be escaped properly or the replace can mess up the file.

Does anyone have a better solution to the problem?

Comment: There´s a `Regex.Escape(string)`. Maybe you can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex to do this. Instead use `element.ReplaceWith(element.Nodes())` to replace node with its children. Sample code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\sample\sample.xml", LoadOptions.None);
// use HashSet, since you only use it for lookups
var ids = new HashSet<string>(from a in doc.Descendants()
    where a.Attribute("id") != null
    select a.Attribute("id").Value);
// select both element itself (for update), and value of "rid"
var xrefs = from x in doc.Descendants("xref")
    where x.Attribute("rid") != null
    select new { element = x, rid = x.Attribute("rid").Value };
if (ids.Any()) {        
    var toUpdate = new List<XElement>();
    foreach (var xref in xrefs) {
        if (!ids.Contains(xref.rid)) {
            toUpdate.Add(xref.element);
        }
    }

    if (toUpdate.Count > 0) {
        foreach (var xref in toUpdate) {
            // replace with contents
            xref.ReplaceWith(xref.Nodes());
        }
        doc.Save(@"D:\sample\sample.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: my files can have multiple `xref` nodes with same `rid` attribute values, so how do I ignore getting the same `xrefs` values and performing the same steps multiple times....I tried replacing `where x.Attribute("rid") != null` with `where x.Attribute("rid") != null && x.Attribute("rid").Value.Distinct()` but get an error `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>'`...?

Comment: I don't see it as a problem. You need to walk over them all, because even if you have multiple xref with the same id - you need to remove them all if id is missing. Do you have a perfomance problem?

Comment: doesn't `xref.ReplaceWith(xref.Nodes());` replace all invalid `xref` nodes or just the first node found is replaced?....I'm not familiar with this method...also I want to run this on many xml files so performance speed is a bit of an issue...if it can be made faster it would be better

Comment: It will replace this specific node (xref in code sample is one node). We first find all invalid, then replace one by one.

Comment: if there are say 3 nodes `<xref ref-type="table" rid="T3">...</xref>` and there are no attribute `id` which has the value `T3` in the entire file it should replace them all in one go right?

Comment: Yes it should. Just run and see yourself.